# OpenGL VBO's not drawing anything

Tags: qt, opengl, vbo

It's been a while since I last worked with VBO's, and now I'm trying to get it working once again. However, whatever I do, I can't get anything to render, besides with glClearColor.

This is my code:

Initialize GL

```
...

vmml::vec3f eye = vmml::vec3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
vmml::vec3f tar = vmml::vec3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
vmml::vec3f up  = vmml::vec3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
viewMatrix = lookAt(eye, tar, up);
```

Creating the box

```
glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 72 * sizeof(GLfloat), &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glGenBuffers(1, &uvBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uvBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 48 * sizeof(GLfloat), &uvs[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glGenBuffers(1, &normalBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 72 * sizeof(GLfloat), &normals[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

[code for adding material and texture to box...]
```

PaintGL

```
    [code for shadows...]

    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    shadeManager.bindShader(SHADOWSHADER);

    vmml::vec4f b1(0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5);
    vmml::vec4f b2(0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.5);
    vmml::vec4f b3(0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.5);
    vmml::vec4f b4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    vmml::mat4f bias = vmml::mat4f::ZERO;
    bias.set_column(0, b1);
    bias.set_column(1, b2);
    bias.set_column(2, b3);
    bias.set_column(3, b4);

    vmml::mat4f depthBiasVP = bias * depthVP;

    GLuint depthBiasID  = glGetUniformLocation(shadowShaderID, "depthBiasVP");
    GLuint lightDirID   = glGetUniformLocation(shadowShaderID, "lightInvDir");
    GLuint shadowMapID  = glGetUniformLocation(shadowShaderID, "shadowMap");
    GLuint viewID       = glGetUniformLocation(shadowShaderID, "V");
    GLuint projectionID = glGetUniformLocation(shadowShaderID, "P");

    glUniformMatrix4fv(depthBiasID, 1, GL_FALSE, &depthBiasVP[0][0]);
    glUniform3fv(lightDirID, 1, &lightPos[0]);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthTextureID);
    glUniform1i(shadowMapID, 1);

    [calculate eye, target and up...]
    viewMatrix = lookAt(eye, target, up);

    glUniformMatrix4fv(viewID, 1, GL_FALSE, &viewMatrix[0][0]);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(projectionID, 1, GL_FALSE, &projectionMatrix[0][0]);

    currentFrustum->setActive(true);
    currentFrustum->extractFrustum(projectionMatrix, viewMatrix);
    scenegraph.render(false);
```

And rendering the box

```
GLuint id = ShaderManager::getInstance().getShader(SHADOWSHADER);
    if (depthPass)
        id = ShaderManager::getInstance().getShader(DEPTHSHADER);

    GLuint mID    = glGetUniformLocation(id, "M");
    GLuint texID  = glGetUniformLocation(id, "tex");
    GLuint diffID = glGetUniformLocation(id, "diffMaterial");
    GLuint ambiID = glGetUniformLocation(id, "ambiMaterial");
    GLuint specID = glGetUniformLocation(id, "specMaterial");
    GLuint shinID = glGetUniformLocation(id, "shininess");

    glUniformMatrix4fv(mID, 1, GL_FALSE, &mod[0][0]);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glUniform1i(texID, 0);

    glUniform3fv(diffID, 1, &values.diffuseMaterial[0]);
    glUniform3fv(ambiID, 1, &values.ambientMaterial[0]);
    glUniform3fv(specID, 1, &values.specularMaterial[0]);
    glUniform1f(shinID, values.shinyMaterial[0]);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(
                0,
                3,
                GL_FLOAT,
                GL_FALSE,
                0,
                (void*)0
                );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uvBuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(
                1,
                2,
                GL_FLOAT,
                GL_FALSE,
                0,
                (void*)0
                );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalBuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(
                2,
                3,
                GL_FLOAT,
                GL_FALSE,
                0,
                (void*)0
                );
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 6 * 4 );

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);
```

Shaders..

```
    #version 420 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPos;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 vertexUV;
layout(location = 2) in vec3 vertexNorm;

out vec2 UV;
out vec3 position;
out vec3 normal;
out vec3 viewDirection;
out vec3 lightDirection;
out vec4 shadow;

uniform mat4 M;
uniform mat4 V;
uniform mat4 P;
uniform vec3 lightInvDir;
uniform mat4 depthBiasVP;

void main() {
    gl_Position = P * V * M * vec4(vertexPos, 1);

    UV = vertexUV;
    position = (M * vec4(vertexPos, 1)).xyz;
    normal = (V * M * vec4(vertexNorm, 0)).xyz;
    viewDirection = vec3(0,0,0) - (V * M * vec4(vertexPos, 1)).xyz;

    lightDirection = (V * vec4(lightInvDir, 0)).xyz;
    shadow = depthBiasVP * M * vec4(vertexPos, 1);
}

#version 420 core

in vec2 UV;
in vec3 position;
in vec3 normal;
in vec3 viewDirection;
in vec3 lightDirection;
in vec4 shadow;

layout(location = 0) out vec3 color;

uniform sampler2D tex;
uniform sampler2D shadowMap;

uniform vec3 diffLight;
uniform vec3 ambiLight;
uniform vec3 specLight;

uniform vec3 diffMaterial;
uniform vec3 ambiMaterial;
uniform vec3 specMaterial;
uniform float shininess;

vec2 disk[16] = vec2[] (
    vec2( -0.94201624, -0.39906216 ), 
    vec2( 0.94558609, -0.76890725 ), 
    vec2( -0.094184101, -0.92938870 ), 
    vec2( 0.34495938, 0.29387760 ), 
    vec2( -0.91588581, 0.45771432 ), 
    vec2( -0.81544232, -0.87912464 ), 
    vec2( -0.38277543, 0.27676845 ), 
    vec2( 0.97484398, 0.75648379 ), 
    vec2( 0.44323325, -0.97511554 ), 
    vec2( 0.53742981, -0.47373420 ), 
    vec2( -0.26496911, -0.41893023 ), 
    vec2( 0.79197514, 0.19090188 ), 
    vec2( -0.24188840, 0.99706507 ), 
    vec2( -0.81409955, 0.91437590 ), 
    vec2( 0.19984126, 0.78641367 ), 
    vec2( 0.14383161, -0.14100790 ) 
);

float random(vec3 seed, int i) {
    vec4 s = vec4(seed, i);
    float dotProduct = dot(s, vec4(12.9898, 78.233, 45.164, 94.673));
    return fract(sin(dotProduct) * 43758.5453);
}

void main() {
    vec3 materialDiffuseColor = diffMaterial * texture2D( tex, UV ).rgb;
    vec3 materialAmbientColor = ambiMaterial * materialDiffuseColor;
    vec3 materialSpecularColor = specMaterial;

    vec3 l = normalize(lightDirection);
    vec3 n = normalize(normal);
    vec3 v = normalize(viewDirection);
    vec3 ref = reflect(-l, n);

    float diff = clamp(dot(n, l), 0,1);
    float spec = clamp(dot(l, ref), 0,1);

    float visibility = 1.0;
    float bias = 0.005*tan(acos(diff));
    bias = clamp(bias, 0.0, 0.01);

    vec4 shadowCoordDivide = shadow / shadow.w;

    if (texture2D( shadowMap, shadowCoordDivide.xy ).z < shadowCoordDivide.z-bias) {
        //visibility = 0.5;
        diff = 0;
        spec = 0;
    }

    color = 2 * ambiLight * materialAmbientColor;

    if (diff != 0) {
        color += visibility * diffLight * materialDiffuseColor * diff;

        float iSpec = pow(spec, shininess);
        color += visibility * specLight * materialSpecularColor * iSpec;
    }
}
```

I've made sure that the shaders are loading properly, and that the model/view/projection matrices are correct, still nothing. Anyone who can point me in the right direction?

Edit1: Added code section I forgot and removed some unimportant code..
Edit2: Stripped code down to possible error areas

Comment: Please don't just dump all your code, narrow it down to where the problem occurs.

Comment: Yeah, there's a lot more code that I didn't dump.. I only posted the relevant areas.

Comment: do you unbind your FBO when it is no longer needed? And bind it again when drawing the shadow map?

Comment: try using an openGL debugger like gDebugger. It will give you info for your VBO and textures and other unifrom/attributes.

Comment: Sigh, I bet I'd find the problem in a matter of seconds, if only I could get gDebugger/CodeXL to work... Have spent the last few hours trying to debug the errors I'm getting when trying to run it...

Comment: What an abominable wall of code. O_o Also, why do you stuff the positions, normals and texcoords into a *seprarate* VBO? Is there any good reason for that?

Comment: @thokra, It's just the way I've been taught to do it, no special reason, really. Anyway, I've managed to narrow the problem down to the shader. The exact same arrays do just what I want them to do when I put them into OpenGL's standard shaders.

Comment: But, the shaders are loaded correctly, the uniforms are found, et cetera. I also have support for the GLSL version I'm running, so I still have no idea... And gDebugger didn't help at all.

Answer (score 0):

Just from looking at your rendering code, it doesn't look like you are passing the View and Perspective matrix to your vertex shader. What happens if you reference a uniform that has not been passed in depends on how nice your GPU drivers are. Some will crash, some will happily feed some default fallback matrix just to get the shader running. It may be that your shader is seeing this default matrix and is not transforming your box correctly.

If you are passing in your matrix correctly elsewhere in your code, than please disregard this answer. Its just based off the code you pasted.

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot that part. I am passing the matrices to the shader.

Comment: Yeah, i figured you were but it never hurts to check :)